# Selectable and Un/Select all button (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I am attempting to make un/select all buttons that will un/highlight all table rows when clicked. It is fairly straight forward to add the ui-selected class to the table, but not make them draggable. Here is my code that demonstrates the selectable/draggable/droppable functionality:

https://jsfiddle.net/Unfixed/s7mtbn26/3/

I currently only have this for the buttons.

```
$("#selectall").on('click', function(evt) {
    $("tr.selectable").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
        });
  evt.preventDefault();
});

    $("#unselectall").on('click', function(evt) {
    $("tr.selectable").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
        });
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

How would I go about making these buttons/links select all of the tables and allow the draggable/droppable functionality to work? Would I have to break my current .selectable() chain into separate functions and use .on() to trigger selectable()?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$("#selectall").on('click', function(evt) {
  $("tr.selectable").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-selected");
  });
  draggables();
  evt.preventDefault();
});

function draggables() {
  $("tr.ui-droppable").draggable('destroy');
  $("tr.ui-droppable").droppable("destroy");
  $("tr.ui-selected").draggable({
    helper: function() {
      var c = $("tr.ui-selected").length;
      var dom = [];
      dom.push("<div style=\"border:2px solid black;width:50px;height:20px;line-height:25px;\">",
        "<center>Files Selected: " + c + "</center></div>");
      return $(dom.join(''));
    },
    revert: 'invalid',
    appendTo: 'parent',
    containment: '#filemanager',
    axis: 'y',
    cursor: '-moz-grabbing'
  });
  $("tr.droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active"
  });
}
```

See updated fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/s7mtbn26/6/

Comment: Thank you :). I ended up having to break everything up into functions to get my full code to work properly. If anyone else is looking to do something similar, not that the Unselect All link is broken in the current fiddle because it does not have .draggable("destroy"); Once added everything works as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Its a custom funtion, please see in fiddle.